# Change style class to div in code using Dojo

Tags: dojo

If I have a `<div id="test"></div>` how do I use Dojo to add and remove style classes from it?
I have tried with `dojo.style("test","class","open");` but it doesn't work. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use dojo.addClass("example1", "style1"); where "example1" - node id, "style1" - class name and dojo.removeClass("example1", "style1");

EDIT:

Also you can use dojo.toggleClass("example1", "style1"); - it function adds a class to node if not present, or removes if present.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
// to add
dojo.attr(dojo.byId("test"), "class" ,"classToAdd");
// to remove
dojo.attr(dojo.byId("test"), "class" ,"");
```

[Try here](http://codepen.io/rohitanandrohit/pen/CyKgB)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dom-class module

```
require(["dojo/dom-class"], function(domClass){
    // Add a class to some node:
    domClass.add("myDOMNode", "myCssClass");
});
```